# What is the point of analysis and biasing calculations when real world performance is going to be much lower in analog circuits?

Tags: amplifier, analog, ltspice, analysis, differential-amplifier

I am making a 3-stage audio amplifier as a course project. The first stage is a differential amplifier, the second stage is a common-emitter amplifier, following that there is a passive filter and lastly I have a class-AB power amplifier to drive the speaker at the output. In my LTSpice simulations and calculations that I did manually, my circuit should produce enough gain to drive my speaker. (The stages are separated by buffers so as to not affect each other's DC biasing)

[image]

So, I started assembling it on a bread-board. I had just put together the differential amplifier and I observed that the gain of the stage itself is much much lower than what the LTspice simulation shows (**the differential amplifier itself in isolation should have a gain of 45 times but the actual circuit on the breadboard only gives me a gain of 15 times**).

The image below shows the output of just the differential amplifier, disconnected from rest of the circuit. Its around 1.85 volts peak to peak for an input of 40 mV peak to peak, but in the actual circuit on breadboard, I am getting around 600 mV peak to peak for the same input.

[image]

Note that the circuit I have assembled on the breadboard isn't driving any load (its just the first stage i.e. the differential amplifier) and the gain is still, lesser than what LTspice predicts for just that stage.

When I asked my professor, they told me that, it is always expected in analog circuits that your performance will be lesser in real world hardware as compared to simulations and that I will have to change the values of resistances and other components to improve gain in the actual circuit.

But, **won't that change my biases?** and also, I am loosing about 2/3rd of my gain (15 times compared to 45 times predicted in simulation). So **where did my gain go?** And **if the performance is going to be much lower in real world hardware (like in this case) than what is the point of analysis and simulations?**

Edit :

R2 and R3 bias voltages : ( voltage across the two ends of the resistors is approximately 4.83 volts for both of them)

[image]

Comment: Can you show the bias condition (particularly R2 and R3 voltages)? You may encounter differences due to device matching, and the SPICE model might not be well fitted for this condition either. Regarding the advice: a *poor* simulation will perform differently than the real thing; whether this reflects upon your professor's capabilities, well, you decide :)

Comment: @TimWilliams I have added the dc voltages across R2 and R3, its approximately 4.83 volts for both of them. Also since my simulation is poor, how do I improve it?

Comment: And on the breadboard?

Comment: @KoustubhJain How well-matched are your ***actual*** breadboarded 2N7000 with respect to their threshold voltages? The datasheets I've looked at show quite a wide range, from maybe 600 mV to 3 V to some even 3.5 V. Even a few tenths of a volt of unmatched difference will significantly impact voltage gain. And their curves don't go anywhere near Id of 500 uA. So gm is who knows?

Comment: The analysis proves that the design can even come close to working. If real hardware always performs worse than the analysis then you can probably throw out any design that doesnt meet your design requirements in analysis. Analysis gets you 80% there. Tuning gets you the rest. Iteration is typical with a lot of designs.

Comment: @KoustubhJain [Here's simulated gain changes with just the slightest variations in Vto, but where the FETs are otherwise *identical*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkch6.png). In the worst case (the lowest gain showing), there's only 200 mV difference. That's only one parameter where the 2N7000 parts are all over the place. There are other parameters, as well dealing with variations in oxide thickness, etc. Insert a source resistor of about 390 Ohms into the two FETs and this degeneration will yield better prediction (near a gain of 9.)

Comment: As others have mentioned, you typically need matched pairs for differential amplifiers. Finding matched BJTs is much easier, but ALD does make MOSFETs in DIP package, although expensive. https://www.aldinc.com/pdf/ALD1101.pdf